# Use android device as emualator

Tags: android-emulator, android

I wanted to use a Motorola Fire XT instead of emulator on my fedora 13. I am using eclipse. i am not running as administrator.

I have enabled USB debugging mode in my phone. But on the DDMS `???????` are shown instead of my phone. Please say how to use. Also , once configured should we have configure every time

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the steps at [Usign Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

You'll need to create and edit the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`and to add the following line to your file :

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22B8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`.

Comment: if we are using android phone as such then should we need to have android sdk? I have an android sdk , but am not sure whether it is  complete, since I have donwloaded it offline. Thanks

Comment: your questions kind of confuses me... but you don't need the sdk to run an app on your device. baiscally there is no such thing as using the device as an emulator...

Comment: actually i meant whethr  we have to downlaod and install android SDK for this.... or will just ADT plugin will do.... also can we see logcat output when we use  real android device just as we see when running android application on emulator

Comment: yes you can see logcat for the device as same as for the emulator

Comment: i have done as said above but when i am about to run the application i see '???????????' symbol where the android device can be selectd

Comment: download respective drivers and you are good to go... solved the same issue with htc wildwifre a while ago.